# Using c# QueueUserWorkItem doesn't seem to execute all the methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread starts and sleeps");
        Student stu = new Student();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 7);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 6);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread ends");
    }

}

public class Student
{
    public  void Display(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Every time I run the code, i get different results. I do not mean the order in which they are displayed.

Following are my various results

```
Main thread starts and sleeps  
Main thread ends


Main thread starts and sleeps
Main thread ends
7
5
6


Main thread starts and sleeps
Main thread ends
7
```

So, why don't i get all three numbers displayed every time. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThreadPool` threads are [background threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx), meaning they are aborted once your main thread ends. Since no one guarantees that your async methods will have a chance to execute before the last statement, you will get different results each time.

Comment: Thanks Groo. I was just using ThreadPool as i was learning various threading methods.

Comment: @Muthukumar: great, but note that while I tried to explain *why* it happens, usually you will still want to know when your tasks are finished, so you should certainly let your background tasks signal when finished (or use .NET 4 Tasks).

Comment: Thanks Groo. I guess this signaling must be one like done in  AutoResetEvent.?

Comment: @Muthukumar: if you need to wait for multiple threads, then you need a list of `AutoResetEvent`s, and need to wait for them all to be signalled. You can also achieve this with different constructs (e.g. semaphores), but in .NET 4 the simplest way is to use the `Parallel` class which does most of the work itself. A great resource on threading is [Albahari's threading e-book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), I recommend reading it thoroughly if you want a deeper understanding of what's really going on. With `Tasks`, many of these concepts are hidden from you.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are not waiting for the tasks to finish. They get queued to be executed on the thread pool, but the main thread exits before all or some of them have completed.

To see all of them finishing you need a synchronization barrier before the end of Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread starts and sleeps");
        Student stu = new Student();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 7);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 6);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(stu.Display, 5);

        // barrier here
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread ends");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, C# does not have a built-in barrier for `ThreadPool`, so you will need to either implement one yourself, or use a different construct, like `Parallel.Invoke`.

Comment: Or use tasks. These days I find myself replacing all threadpool construct with tasks.